# c# WCF HTTP rest client with WebHttpBinding/Behavior for POSTing RAW data in request body

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, http-post

I have a HTTP REST service endpoint I want to connect to send an XML stream in RAW format. Therefore I created a client side service contract "IHttpXmlClient" with a respective ClientBase inherited implementation.

```
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.IO;

namespace MyNamespace
{
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IHttpXmlClient
  {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, Method = "POST")]
    void Send(Stream data);
  }

  public class HttpXmlClient : ClientBase<IHttpXmlClient>, IHttpXmlClient
  {
    public void Send(Stream data)
    {
      Channel.Send(data);
    }
  }
}
```

As configuration I defined the following in my App.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://thehttpxmlserver.com:8000/receiver?client=itsme"
          binding="webHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="webHttp_HttpXmlClient"
          contract="MyNamespace.IHttpXmlClient"
          behaviorConfiguration="HttpXmlClientEndpointBehavior">
    </endpoint>
  </client>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="webHttp_HttpXmlClient">
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="HttpXmlClientEndpointBehavior">
        <webHttp />       
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The implementation to connect the HTTP REST service endpoint and send the respective XML data looks like this:

```
var myXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><root>Hello World</root>";
using (var data = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myXml)))
{
  var client = new HttpXmlClient();
  client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "myuser";
  client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "mypassword";
  client.Open();
  client.Send(data);
}
```

Everything is just working perfectly except the "content-type" HTTP header contains the wrong information. I used fiddler to trace the raw outgoing information from my machine. Here goes the result:

```
POST http://thehttpxmlserver.com:8000/receiver?client=itsme HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Authorization: Basic bXl1c2VyOm15cGFzc3dvcmQ=
Host: thehttpxmlserver.com:8000
Content-Length: 65
Expect: 100-continue

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root>Hello World</root>
```

What I want is to set the "content-type" header to the value "text/xml;charset=UTF-8". Is that possible somehow? Of course I want to keep my above implementation and I definitely don't want to implement a manual WebRequest, where I loose the easy configuration in my application's config file!

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by adding the following code to my ClientBase inherited class:

```
public class HttpXmlClient : ClientBase<IHttpXmlClient>, IHttpXmlClient
{
  public void Send(Stream data)
  {
    using (new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel) Channel))
    {
      var request = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest;
      request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8";
      Channel.Send(data);
    }
  }
}
```